# get boolean value from access database in c#

Tags: c#, .net, database, ms-access, boolean

I have written a program in C# .Net framework that uses the Access database and the accesses of each user to different sections are stored in it in Boolean format.

I had a problem to check whether they are True or False from the database.

I just need to know how to import these values from Access and store them in other variables to access them.

login form source code

```
public partial class FormLogin : Form
    {
        static OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=kft21_gym.accdb");
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("", con);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        Boolean BlResult = false;
        
        public Boolean Bsabtnam = false;
        public Boolean Bmodiriathamrahan = false;
        public Boolean Bbaresisavabegh = false;
        public Boolean Bmodiriatkomod = false;
        public Boolean Bmodiriatkarbaran = false;
        public Boolean Bgetbackup = false;
        public Boolean Bgetrestore = false;

        public FormLogin()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Checking()
        {
            string check = "SELECT ID FROM Login WHERE UserName='" + txtUserName.Text + "' AND UserPassword='" + txtPassword.Text + "' ";
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(check, con);
            da.Fill(ds, "t1");

            if (ds.Tables["t1"].Rows.Count != 0)
            {
                BlResult = true;
                this.BackgroundImage = imgTrue.Image;
                lblEnter.Visible = true;

                //need to change them if the value is TRUE
                /*
                Bsabtnam = ???????
                Bmodiriathamrahan = ???????
                Bbaresisavabegh = ???????
                Bmodiriatkomod = ???????
                Bmodiriatkarbaran = ???????
                Bgetbackup = ???????
                Bgetrestore = ???????
                */
            }
            else
            {
                BlResult = false;
                this.BackgroundImage = imgFalse.Image;
                lblEnter.Visible = false;
            }
        }

        private void txtUserName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Checking();
        }

        private void txtPassword_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Checking();
        }

        private void txtUserName_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Convert.ToInt32(e.KeyChar) == 13 && BlResult == true)
            {
                this.Close();
            }
            else if(Convert.ToInt32(e.KeyChar) == 27)
            {
                Application.Exit();
            }
        }

        private void txtPassword_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Convert.ToInt32(e.KeyChar) == 13 && BlResult == true)
            {
                this.Close();
            }
            else if (Convert.ToInt32(e.KeyChar) == 27)
            {
                Application.Exit();
            }
        }

        private void FormLogin_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (BlResult == false)
            {
                Application.Exit();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide code of what you have.  Its easier for people to help when they see what you have tried.

Comment: IMHO "as soon as possible" feels unnecessary

Comment: Why would boolean be any different than reading other data? Can you actually read data from your access database? If yes, what issue do you face that is related soley to boolean? If no, better ask how to read ANY data from access database.

Comment: You are only selecting `ID` from the table. If you want to read other fields you will need to add them to your SQL query. Such old tech as data adapters will have volumes of material online. I expect you can find examples of reading from them. Unrelated, but concatenating text to build SQL is prone to causing syntax errors and SQL injection attacks. Use [parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/configuring-parameters-and-parameter-data-types)

Answer (score 0):

Well, if your question is how to get the data out of the loaded table then (working off some pretty old memories) I believe the answer is to use double indexing in the table:

```
dim value as Variant
dim table as …
table = ds.Tables[“t1”]
value = table[i][j]
```

On the other hand if your question is how to access booleans as compared to, say, double or string … as I recall bools are stored as integers in Access. So check the variant and see if it is an int.